# Como convertir un float a char?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa para una tarjeta STM32F103 y estoy obteniendo variables de tipo float y para enviarlas facilmente debo convertirla a char

Por ejemplo tenemos

```
int main(){    
   float a = 12.9898;
   char con[6];
   print("Valor: %s",con);
   return 0;
}
```

intente con la funcion

```
int j = snprintf(con, 6, "%f\n", a);
```

Pero no imprime nada incluso intente castearlo, ¿cómo puedo hacer para convertirlo?
Que regrese como cadena el valor `12.9898`

Comment: 12.9898 ocupa 7 caracteres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en una de las respuestas de [**ésta pregunta**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988791/converting-float-to-char), puedes hacerlo con el método [**`sprintf()`**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm):

```
sprintf(con, "%.4f", a);
```

En donde:

- El primer argumento es el arreglo donde se almacenará el resultado (`char con[6]`).
- El segundo indicas que quieres imprimir un número flotante con 4 dígitos después del decimal.
- El tercer argumento es el valor flotante que vamos a convertir.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){    
   float a = 12.9898;
   char con[6];
   sprintf(con, "%.4f", a);
   printf("Valor: %s\n",con);
   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
// Valor: 12.9898
```

Comment: Lo correcto sería usar la versión segura `snprintf_s`. https://youtu.be/Qyn1qxi73u8

Answer (score 2):

Como ha dicho @Mateo deberías usar la versión más segura de [snprintf](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/)
Y tener en cuenta la longitud del array que utilizas para guardar el float. En tu caso (12.9898) necesitarás 7 bytes (contando el punto) + 1 byte de terminación.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){    
   float a = 12.9898;
   char con[8];
   snprintf(con,sizeof(con), "%.4f", a);       
   printf("Valor: %s\n",con);
   return 0;
}
```

*Output:* Valor: 12.9898

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwEETv@YolUmggFhUPqVU/w4v1ENLEBuJGkvSi@O0xLR0Y2Bnmrdo@lcp5Y1G5adBwjmmwvhmvhFhM8JIWa/aFIlJsnJcJJFxgf2ha0YpubtUoAyiPd/FYcsR3KLCpS8ej/Wi/nIwDrZqjoRwk62DVDKxz2uNNOh9OUMUeKZ@Z5WHQaQoIu478cv4D)

Answer (score 1):

Así quedaría el código con la función `sprintf` para convertir `a` a un string y almacenarla en `con`. Ahí solo para mencionar que la longitud máxima de `con` es 20 para asegurar que tiene suficiente espacio para almacenar el número en formato de texto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    // Your code here!
   float a = 12.9898;
   char con[20];
   sprintf(con, "%f", a);
   printf("Valor: %s", con);
   return 0;
}
```

El output que debería arrojarte es el siguiente:

```
Valor: 12.989800
```